# How to choose one version of the drivers to be loaded on boot when multiple drivers for the same hardware exist?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, kernel-module

I'm working with embedded linux.

There are two USB gadget drivers built as [LKM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadable_kernel_module), [g_ether.ko and g_file_storage.ko](http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/).

I did `depmod` and then in `modprobe -l` both drivers show up in the list.

```
kernel/drivers/usb/gadget/g_ether.ko
kernel/drivers/usb/gadget/g_file_storage.ko
```

**The problem is, the kernel doesn't load either of them on boot anatomically.**

Curently my solution is to add boot scripts to `/etc/init.d` `etc/rcX.d` to force `g_ether.ko` to be loaded on boot as the default driver.

Are there other (better) ways to make `g_ether.ko` default driver?

A possible solution is, I make `g_ether.ko` a static driver, and make `g_file_storage.ko` an LKM, but I don't know how to turn off a static driver to release the hardware so that another LKM driver can be loaded.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a user choice to use USB peripheral controller as ethernet or storage. So there is no related hardware event for automatic client driver loading.

But there is a way to bind/unbind driver in user space through sysfs. Look at this： https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/